# Function that calculates mean and variance for all data frame columns

Tags: python

I want to create a function that calculates mean and variance from a pandas data frame for all columns.

Here I made an example using a list. It would be nice if it can be one function that does both calculations:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

def mean(a):  
    q = 0   
    for x in a:
        q += x
    return (1.0*q)/len(a)

def variance(a):
    q = 0
    d = 0
 `   for x in a:
        i = x - mean(a)
        c = i**2
        d = d+c

    v = d /len(a)
    return v

print (variance(a))
print(np.var(a))
`
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html

Comment: Before I go micro-optimizing your code, WHY do you want to do this, when `numpy` provides excellent statistics functions already?

Comment: You can replace your `mean` function with `return sum(a)/len(a)`.  And don't recompute the mean every time through your loop.  If you just gather a sum and the sum of squares, you can compute the variance directly as `(sum-of-squares)/N - (sum/N) squared`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the sum of your data in both calculations, like this:

```
def mean_and_variance(arr):
    s = np.sum(arr)
    N = len(arr)
    mean = s / N
    variance = (s ** 2) / N - (s / N) ** 2
    return mean, variance
```

Altough the improvement in execution time might still be higher than plain `numpy`, depending on the size of your vector.